# Send database by sending List<record>

Tags: c#, database, list

I had a Windows Service. It will check database every 5 mins and if there're new record, it will send to a web service to save data in another database.

My WS send record one by one and now I want to send a List. The problem is if there're many new records, I want to divide it into multiple list (like 50 records each list) and send them one by one.

I wonder how can I do it, anyone have a solution for this case ? Tks so much

Comment: Is `record` a [`DbDataRecord`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatarecord.aspx) instance? What DAL are you using, ADO.NET? Do you want paging at the client(win-service) or already in the database?

Comment: Record is a row in a table of Database. I used c#. The Web Service already done. Now I want to improve my Windows Service.

Comment: C# is the language not a DAL like ADO.NET,Linq-To-SQL,Entity-Framework,NHibernate,DataSet, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take the list of changed/new records. We'll call this the "list to send".
2. Create a sublist with only the first 50 records of the list to send.
3. Send that sublist to the webservice.
4. Remove those 50 records from the list to send.
5. If the list to send is not empty, repeat from step 2.